# Remove all but one occurance of word in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a string for example "Free Visual Studio developer offers offers offers offers with everything you need to create apps"
what i want to do is "offers" is occuring 4 times sequentially; i want to keep "offers" just once and remove all the other occurances.
This is just an example string,i have a dataset where such cases are there of same words occuring sequentially more than once,
Please help me a way to remove other such words and keep one word and generate a resulting string

Comment: a) split your string on whitespace to produce a list of words. b) Apply the solution in the duplicate question. c) re-join the resulting list with a space again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find repeating words and remove the extra ones:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Free Visual Studio developer offers offers offers offers with everything you need to create apps'
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\w+\s)(\1+)', '\\1', s)
'Free Visual Studio developer offers with everything you need to create apps'
```